return a reference to a static-variable inside a class-template
I have difficulty understanding the reason for the following error.
If I define a template class:
template<typename I, typename V> class core
{  
public:
  I idx;   
};

which is used as a static variable inside another template class:
template <typename B, typename I> class outer
{
private:
  static B null_core;
public:
  outer()
  {
    if(null_core.idx != -1) 
      null_core = {-1};    
  }
  B& get(const I idx)
  {
      return null_core;
  }
};

I will get the following error:
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /tmp/ccIxNK1O.o: in function `outer<core<int, double>, int>::outer()':
hash2.cxx:(.text._ZN5outerI4coreIidEiEC2Ev[_ZN5outerI4coreIidEiEC5Ev]+0xa): undefined reference to `outer<core<int, double>, int>::null_core'
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: hash2.cxx:(.text._ZN5outerI4coreIidEiEC2Ev[_ZN5outerI4coreIidEiEC5Ev]+0x15): undefined reference to `outer<core<int, double>, int>::null_core'
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /tmp/ccIxNK1O.o: in function `outer<core<int, double>, int>::get(int)':
hash2.cxx:(.text._ZN5outerI4coreIidEiE3getEi[_ZN5outerI4coreIidEiE3getEi]+0xc): undefined reference to `outer<core<int, double>, int>::null_core'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

And, below is a sample usage:
int main()
{
  outer<core<int,double>, int> th;
  core<int, double> &tc = th.get(2024);
  std::cout << std::endl<< tc.idx << std::endl;

  return 0;
}

If I remove the word static from the definition of the null_core, then everything compiles and links perfectly and the results are valid.

Does this answer your question? Can template classes have static members in C++

First thing comes to my mind is actually how can a static member be of different types, which is exactly what you are requesting, isn't it? If outer<int,int> first; and outer<double, double> second. Then core has to be int and double at the same time?

Where is your definition of the outer::null_core member? You have declared it, but like any other static data member, it still needs a storage definition outside of the class, and since core is templated then you need a separate definition for each instantiation of core that you actually use, eg: template <typename B, typename I> class outer { ... }; ... core<int,double> outer<core<int,double>, int>::null_core;

@Nyquist -- outer<int, int> and outer<double, double> are two different types. Each one has its own members, just like struct S { static int x; }; struct T { static double x; };.

Ah yeah, of course. Then they are different pieces of memory, thanks!

@AviBerger: Thanks for the link. It is almost the same except the "inline" technique suggested by Christian Stieber (see below) was not included in that link.

@RemyLebeau: Yes that was my problem. I didn't know that we should (storage)define static members outside the class. I still can't grasp it :(

@argasm just like class methods are declared and defined separately unless you inline them, the same applies to static data members, too.

@RemyLebeau I still don't understand. I sometimes define data and methods inside the class definition and I don't explicitly define them outside. And, this way has been working very well and I never have doubted it so never gone into more details...  The first time I see this behavior is happening for static members! Am I missing somethig?

Instance (non-static) data members form a part of the class data. There is a different one for each class instance. They are created with each instance and the requisite memory to accommodate them is part of the memory that is provisioned for each class instance. static data members are only one per class, mot instance. So when memory is provisioned for class instances, none is included for them. They need  to be created and have memory provisioned for them separately, once only independent of any particular class instance.

"If I define a template class:" -- What if you don't? The simpler you make your example, the easier it is to identify what is important. Eliminating a template nets a huge gain in simplification. What if you declared null_core as static int null_core; instead? It's not your end goal, but if you get the same error, you've eliminated a red herring.

@JaMiT the null_core is a complex data type and has many more members. I just eliminated them all to simplify the question. Unfortunately, I can't use the features I need if I don't template it.

@argasm "I sometimes define data and methods inside the class definition and I don't explicitly define them outside" - that falls under the "inlining" I was referring to.

@argasm "I can't use the features I need if I don't template it" -- Are those the features you need for your project (which is not relevant for your Stack Overflow question) or the features you need to present a [mre] that focuses on getting the "undefined reference" error? Why does the MRE need null_core.idx instead of simply null_core?

Well, your problem is that you have declared the static, but not defined it.
The easiest way is to make it inline:
template <typename B, typename I> class outer
{
   static inline B null_core;
   ...
}

Or you can define it outside of the class:
template <typename B, typename I> class outer
{
   static B null_core;
   ...
};

template <typename B, typename I> B outer<B,I>::null_core;


I like the "inline" feature because it reduces the code lines. Thank you

@argasm I think it's C++17, though. It's also a lot less messy and more readable, IMHO.

yep. On my terminal it says -std C++1X or gnu g++1X

An alternative here is to move the static member as static variable of the method:
template <typename B, typename I> class outer
{
public:
  outer() = default;

  B& get(const I)
  {
      static B null_core{-1};
      return null_core;
  }
};

